# Launch MyApp from a link on Android, but not in the Activity declared as MAIN

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm launching MyApp from a URL.

I declared the intent and it works:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

   <data   android:scheme =    "https"
           android:host =      "formiik.com"
           android:pathPrefix ="/citas"/>
   <data   android:scheme  =   "http"
           android:host =      "www.formiik.com"
           android:pathPrefix ="/citas"/>
</intent-filter>
```

But intent only works when it is declared with the intent.action.MAIN on the Activity.

If I put the intent to launch or in another Activity, the intent doesn't catch the URL.

Can't I launch it into another Activity that is not MAIN?

Or I need another instruction?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intent looks fine,  make sure the other activity you want it on has `android:exported="true"` because it's not a launcher activity and then you should be good to go!